# Show session django_timezone in template

Tags: python, django, session, datetime

I'd like to add timezone functionality to my site. I've installed [django_easy_timezones](https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones) and also [added form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) so that the user can change it.

It works ok (although sitewide form in header using ajax would be better), but I would like to show the user/anonymous what is the  currently selected timezone. I thought the following would work.

```
{{ request.session.django_timezone }}
```

However it is not showing anything (maybe its `Null`?).

If I pass `request.session['django_timezone']` through views, it works. It prints `Europe/Prague` in my case.

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't `{{ request.session.django_timezone }}` work?
2. Can I print "UTC+1" instead of long string timezone like `America/North_Dakota/New_Salem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't know why, but it started working. Probably just restart got it working.
2. I don't know how to implement +1 instead of timezones now, but I leave it as it is for now. If want it to be shorter, I will just crop it from last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case I think this one can help you:

https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect

I already used and works fine!

Comment: I tried to install it, but it gives me `Error during template rendering` on this line `{% tz_detect %}`. Anyway, I looked at it's code and there is also session for `detected_tz` instead of `django_timezone`. So it would not solve my first question. It might solve second question, since there is offset to be set. It also doesn't use geoip for timezone detection, that easy_timezones is.

Comment: I was missing `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. So form to set offset should be on `/tz-detect/set/` url? I get blank page.